# Is it possible to wire Spring Data Redis repositories manually in beans.xml?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

Our Spring Boot Test suite runs by using a beans xml file specifically for testing (@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:site-beans-test.xml"})).

We've been using Spring Data JPA and just added Spring Data Redis (1.7.2).  I have a @Repository interface that extends CrudRepository, where Token is a class annotated with @RedisHash.

This works fine when building without test (-Dmaven.test.skip=true), however when running the tests they fail with:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.service.domain.redis.repository.TokenRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency
```

With Spring Data JPA there is a `<jpa:repositories base-package="..." />` tag that can be used to correctly wire the repository proxies.

Is there a way to do that for Spring Data Redis repositories?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Redis used `@EnableRedisRepositories()` annotation to configure the location of your redis repositories. It can be used as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = "com.orm.repo")
public class RedisConfiguration {

}
```

This will enable  you to separates JPA repositories from Redis Repositories. 
This also can also be used to resolve:
`Did you forget to provide one using @Id?` when working with JPA repositories as `spring-data-redis` tries to load other objects annotated with `@Repository`.